# SQL - Count number of itemactive within a date rate

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date-range

I have a dataset of `Resources`, `Projects`, `StartDate` and `EndDate`.
Each Resource can be utilised by multiple projects.

I want to get a count of the number of projects that are using a resource in each quarter.

So if  project starts in Q1 of a particular year and ends in Q3 that year, and project2 starts in Q2 and ends in Q3, I want to get a count of 2 projects for Q2, since during Q1 both project1 and project2 were active.

Here is my dataset:

```
create table Projects
(Resource_Name varchar(20)
,Project_Name varchar(20)
,StartDate varchar(20)
,EndDate varchar(20)
)


insert into Projects values('Resource 1','Project A','15/01/2013','1/11/2014')
insert into Projects values('Resource 1','Project B','1/03/2013','1/09/2016')
insert into Projects values('Resource 1','Project C','1/04/2013','1/09/2015')
insert into Projects values('Resource 1','Project D','1/06/2013','1/03/2016')
insert into Projects values('Resource 1','Project E','15/01/2013','1/09/2015')
insert into Projects values('Resource 1','Project F','3/06/2013','1/11/2015')
```

And here is the result I'm looking for:

```
Resource Name| Year | Quarter|Active Projects
Resource 1     2013     1           2
Resource 1     2013     2           6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using tally table:

Using the dates from `Projects`, generate a list of all quarters and their start dates and end dates, in this example, that  is `CteQuarter(sd, ed)`. After that, you simply need to `JOIN` the `Projects` table to `CteQuarter` for overlapping dates. Then finally, `GROUP BY` using the `YEAR` and `Quarter` part of the date.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e4cff/1/0)

```
WITH CteYear(yr) AS(
    SELECT number
    FROM master..spt_values
    WHERE 
        type = 'P'
        AND number >= (SELECT MIN(YEAR(CONVERT(DATE, StartDate, 103))) FROM Projects)
        AND number <= (SELECT MAX(YEAR(CONVERT(DATE, EndDate, 103))) FROM Projects)
),
CteQuarter(sd, ed) AS(
    SELECT
        DATEADD(QUARTER, q.n - 1, DATEADD(YEAR, cy.yr - 1900, 0)),
        DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(QUARTER, q.n, DATEADD(YEAR, cy.yr - 1900, 0)))
    FROM CteYear AS cy
    CROSS JOIN(
        SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4
    ) AS q(n)
)
SELECT 
    p.Resource_Name,
    [Year] = DATEPART(YEAR, q.sd),
    [Quarter] = DATEPART(QUARTER, q.sd),
    [Active Projects] = COUNT(*)
FROM Projects p
INNER JOIN CteQuarter q
    ON CONVERT(DATE, StartDate, 103) <= q.ed
    AND CONVERT(DATE, EndDate, 103) >= q.sd
GROUP BY 
    p.Resource_Name,
    DATEPART(YEAR, q.sd),
    DATEPART(QUARTER, q.sd)
ORDER BY
    p.Resource_Name,
    DATEPART(YEAR, q.sd),
    DATEPART(QUARTER, q.sd)
```

Notes:

1. [**Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/325964/2203084) is a great way to check for overlapping dates.
2. [Some common date routines](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/lynnpettis/2009/03/25/some-common-date-routines/)

---

RESULT:

```
| Resource_Name | Year | Quarter | Active Projects |
|---------------|------|---------|-----------------|
|    Resource 1 | 2013 |       1 |               3 |
|    Resource 1 | 2013 |       2 |               6 |
|    Resource 1 | 2013 |       3 |               6 |
|    Resource 1 | 2013 |       4 |               6 |
|    Resource 1 | 2014 |       1 |               6 |
|    Resource 1 | 2014 |       2 |               6 |
|    Resource 1 | 2014 |       3 |               6 |
|    Resource 1 | 2014 |       4 |               6 |
|    Resource 1 | 2015 |       1 |               5 |
|    Resource 1 | 2015 |       2 |               5 |
|    Resource 1 | 2015 |       3 |               5 |
|    Resource 1 | 2015 |       4 |               3 |
|    Resource 1 | 2016 |       1 |               2 |
|    Resource 1 | 2016 |       2 |               1 |
|    Resource 1 | 2016 |       3 |               1 |
```

Comment: Q: what `DATEADD(YEAR, cy.yr - 1900, 0)` does?

Comment: Gets the first day of the year `cy.yr`.

Comment: Ok, but why you need the 1900?

Comment: Because the  date `0` means `1900-01-01`.

Comment: @FelixPamittan You need to make change to your CteYear. I changed the end date of first Project A to 2015 from 2014. Now your solution doesn't show 2014. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c2236/1

Comment: Q: If I have a DimDate table, with all the possible dates, do I still need the first 2 CTEs?

Comment: I know what he did. Not sure yet _how_. First have a list of `years` to cover the data. Then split all those years in `quarters` with begin and end date. The check each `quarter` and see how many project have some portion on that `quarter`

Comment: @FelixPamittan you need to use recursion to get all the years in your cteyr. Something like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c2236/16

Comment: @jmich738, no need, as long as you can generate the start and end dates of each quarter.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by determining the first and last quarters when a project is active, and then using cumulative sum.  In SQL Server 2012+, this looks like

```
select resource_name, yyyyq, 
       (sum(sum(s)) over (partition by resource_name order by yyyyq) -
        sum(sum(e)) over (partition by resource_name order by yyyyq) +
        e
       ) as activeProjects
from ((select resource_name, datepart(year, startdate) + datepart(quarter, startdate) as yyyyq, 1 as s, 0 as e
       from projects
      ) union all
      (select resource_name, datepart(year, enddate) + datepart(quarter, enddate), 0 as s, 1 as e
       from projects
      )
     ) yq
group by resource_name, yyyyq;
```

In earlier versions, you can do something similar with `cross apply`.